# What is this regex supposed to match - h*

Tags: c#, regex

I have a piece of code that is supposed look through a list of strings to match a regular expression whose pattern is an input from the user. Inputs such as

h*

q*

y*

seem to match anything and everything. My questions -

1. Is any of the above a valid regex pattern at all?
2. If yes, what exactly are they supposed to match?

I've gone through http://regexhero.net/reference/ but couldn't find anything that specifies such expression.

I've used http://regexhero.net/tester/ to check what my regex matches with **q*** as the Regular Expression and **Whatever** as the Target String. It gives me **9** matches!

Comment: Check out `*` under the "Quantifiers" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These patterns match any number of the specified character, including zero. Without any anchors, there are 9 places where there are zero `q` in `whatever` (between the characters and at the ends).

Out of your reference:

- Ordinary characters — Characters other than `. $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \` match themselves.
- `*` — Repeat 0 or more times matching as many times as possible.

Comment: And there's more 'non-ordinary' characters which behave differently depending on the situation. `(?: ... )` is one example which involves `:`. By itself, `:` would have been considered 'ordinary', but not here.

Comment: @Pavel, thanks! That's the kind of explanation I was looking for. I was just so confused when it showed 9 matches for "whatever".  
"9 places where there are zero q in whatever (between the characters and at the ends)." - that cleared all my doubts!

Answer (score 3):

`h*` means *zero or more `h` characters*

The same for the others